Data Portability API
Dear LinkedIn Support Team,
I am writing to you today regarding the Pages Data Portability API. I am a systems analyst at Kommo, and I am currently working on integrating our CRM system with LinkedIn.
I have gained access to the API, but I am encountering some confusion regarding its capabilities. The methods that I am seeing appear to be limited to reading data only. I do not see any methods for creating data, entities, or posting to the API.
I would greatly appreciate it if you could clarify this for me. Is my understanding correct that the Pages Data Portability API is only for reading data? Or are there other methods available for creating and modifying data on LinkedIn?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance. I look forward to hearing back from you soon.
Best regards,
Alex
